# How to play an mp3 on an iPhone without installing anything?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I play an mp3 on an iPhone 7 (iOS 14) without installing a third party mp3 player?

Comment: iTunes would seem like the obvious answer… why not that?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I use the Music.app in 14.5, and all I have are .mp3

Comment: @Tetsujin I think iTunes doesn't exist for iOS 14, I have only iTunes Store and Music, and I can't choose "Open with.." for eiher of them

Comment: @red_menace how do you open the mp3 in Music?

Comment: I just play it.  Is getting the file(s) onto the device the actual problem?

Comment: Where is this mp3? [btw 'iTunes' == 'Music'] <rant>Why anyone would rename one of the most recognisable app names on the planet to something as non-unique as 'Music' beggars belief.</rant>

Comment: @red_menace actually, I can play it from inside of the Files app

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree with you. I'm also not a fan of needing an accessory app on top of it for buying any kind of non-subscription music.

Comment: I don't actually have any subscription music. I'm most definitely *not* in the target market for 'renting' music. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be played from inside of the Files app

Comment: I just manually manage my music, drag-and-drop from the Finder, and they show up in Music.

Comment: @red_menace you're clearly on macOS, this quesiton is for an iPhone

Comment: I understand that, and _am_ talking about an iPhone.  I just mentioned how I put the .mp3 music files on my phone so that they show up in the Music.app, without having to use anything else such as Files.